# Can i add some data like header or footer to PDF in Android?

Tags: android

i am trying to add some data like header & footer to PDF in Android.but i am not aware about how to add data to PDF file.i want to add data at footer side i.e at the top or bottom. in market i have seen Applications [Application_market](https://market.android.com/search?q=signature+PDF&so=1&c=apps). i want same functionality which they have used there...

Can anyone suggest me or guide for the same or give some sample of it..
Thanks in Advance-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/). It is a Java/C# library that allows you to manipulate pdf files. There are various examples available that show how to add a header/footer:

http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221

Comment: ok...but i am not aware about that.can you please give me some sample of it or library sample...???

Comment: @Smith I changed my answer and added a sample link

Comment: thanks  lot..i will try to understand what u have given if there are issues then i will approach to you....

Comment: i saw it,but it will be  allows us to add header  in Android PDF file with the help of iText???